# How can I compare distributions using only mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, distribution, random-variables, stationarity

I only have means and standard deviations of samples of two random variables.  What technique can I use to determine how similar the distributions these describe are?  Assume that the values are built from very similar samples.  I'm looking for a mechanism to detect when the distributions deviate from one another by some threshold.  Access to historical observations is limited.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which distributions the data follow based on the mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of different tests that are generally used to compare samples to different distributions, such as [Jarque-Bera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test), [Anderson-Darling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test), and [Kolmogorov–Smirnov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) (see [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/appropriate-normality-tests-for-small-samples)).

In your case, with just the standard deviation and mean, there isn't a whole lot to say.  You need to assume a distribution (e.g. normal).  You would be able to tell much more if you could at least get the [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis).

Answer (score 6):

Be careful, remember that the mean and the standard deviation don't tell you the whole story: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet